# NPS wont run or install, error code 0x80070643

Tags: windows-server-2008, nps

Installing `NPS` results in the error below:

> attempt to install network policy server failed with error code 0x80070643 fatal error during installation

The SBS server ran an update on Friday and since then, `NPS` has not worked.  I have checked permissions on `system32\IAS` and the `builtin` OU, but still cannot run `NPS`. My last attempt to remove and reinstall has now left the machine unable to install `NPS` at all!

Has anyone seen this or have a direction to suggest? Google has shown other people haven't been able to resolve it.

The server manager log shows the below:

```
[CbsUIHandler] Error: -2147023293 : 2011-03-08 09:41:20.515 
[CbsUIHandler] Terminate: 2011-03-08 09:41:20.515 
[CBS] Error (Id=0) Function: 'NativeMethods.GetPackageStatus(out status)' 80070643 (-2147023293) 2011-03-08 09:41:20.515
[CBS] ...done installing 'IAS NT Service '. Status: -2147023293 (80070643) 2011-03-08 09:41:20.515
[InstallationProgressPage] Verifying installation... 2011-03-08 09:41:20.546 
[Provider] Skipped configuration of 'NetworkPolicyServer' because install operation failed.
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue by executing "sfc.exe /scannow"

Comment: Please give a bit more details. Any downsides?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the resolutions suggested by Microsoft in [KB958052](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/958052)?

If that doesn't work, you could try to remove every .NET-installation on the server and then clean it up with the [.NET Framework CleanUp Tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/08/28/8904493.aspx). Afterwards, try reinstalling them if you need them and run the updates again.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, it got slightly upset when .Net was cleared up. Although I don't think its a framework issue I thought it was worth a try! I looked at the servermanager log and got this snippet

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the value for `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` Reg_Word key under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\VSS\VssAccessControl`

   If this is set to 0 change the value to 1.
2. Stop “World Wide Web Publishing Service (W3SVC)”
3. Remove (save in Temp folder) all files from `Windows\System32\ias` folder
4. Copy from a good Windows 2008 R2 machine the `dnary.xsd` file
5. Install Network Policy Server role
6. Restart the server.

From: http://blog.montarel.com/tech/2013/10/nps-install-failed-with-error-code-0x80070643/